# Get only text from html with html agility

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to remove from the html everything that is concerned to html with html agility, but I need to keep the text. For example, from this tag:

```
<TR><TD> 
<B><A HREF="survival/index.html">Survival</A></B><BR> 
<I>Be Suspicious, Be Worried, Be Prepared</I><BR> 
<TD>
```

I want to keep only "Be suspicious..."

I have this method, but doesn't work very well:

```
    private static HtmlDocument RemoveHTML(HtmlDocument document)
    {
        HtmlDocument textOfDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p|.//title|.//body"))
        {
            var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(node.InnerText+" ");
            textOfDoc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(newNode);
        }
        return textOfDoc;
    }
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only extracting P, TITLE and BODY tags. If you want I tags as well, you need to do this:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//p|.//title|.//body|.//i")
```

Comment: Hmm not, that's not what I wanted, because what I wanted is to select the text from a page to index it with Lucene.

What I did in the end was clean the html code with a library like Tidy of .Net and then if I add to foreach ".//p|.//title|.//body" it works very well.

But thanks either! :)